# Python - Keep refreshing data whilst also alowing User Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I am using the module `mysql.connector`, I am making a small console messaging app. I am able to keep refreshing the data as long as I don't ask for user input. However, I need user input so people can    send messages, is there a way I can allow the data to keep updating and allow messages to be sent

Code

```
while True:
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port="3306",
    user="root",
    database="pythondb"
    )

    cursor = db.cursor()

    for message in fetchMessages():
        if(message.sender == socket.gethostname()):
            print(f"You: {encryption.decode('goldenwonders', message.message)}")
        else:
            print(f"{message.sender}: {encryption.decode('goldenwonders', message.message)}")

    
    
    message = input("\nPlease Enter a Message: ")
    message = encryption.encode('goldenwonders', message)
    sender = socket.gethostname()
        
    sql = "INSERT INTO messages (message, sender) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    values = (message, sender)

    cursor.execute(sql, values)
    db.commit() 

    cursor.close()
    db.close()
```

Here is the `fetchMessages` function just in-case

```
def fetchMessages():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM messages")
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    messages.clear()
    os.system('cls')
    for x in results:
        messages.append(Message(x[1], x[2]))

    return messages
```

I hope someone can provide an answer.

Thanks for any Help!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the question I am not able to understand it. Also can't you try socket programming?

Comment: @chowmean  If I remove the send message code and manually insert a value into the DB, the program will update and display that new data but if the send message code is added the displayed data will not update until a message is sent or the program is restarted. I cannot use Sockets as this is for a School Project and you have to use Databases, I would've used sockets otherwise

Comment: I think you will need to use multithreading\multiprocessing so the input and fetch run separately